# syntax error near unexpected token `(' in rust

Tags: syntax, rust

I typed my first code in rust. The helloworld. But I got an error when I tried to run it.

```
fn main() {
    println!("Hello world");
}
```

I tried to run using './hellworld.rs'
But it showed,

```
syntax error near unexpected token `('
`fn main() {'
```

Comment: Same issue with hello world example on termux using rustc to compile and bash to run

Comment: Instead try to execute the compiled `main` instead of `main.rs` that solved it for me

Answer (score 6):

I was using powershell. But used the wrong command `./helloworld.rs`
Instead I tried `./helloworld` and `./helloworld.exe`. Both worked.